# How to communicate with two PC using RS232

Tags: rs232

I was just wondering that is this possible to communicate with two computers using RS232 using  softwares like docklight and putty. Suppose if i send Hi from on pc will it recive in another PC and vice versa.

Comment: OF COURSE it is possible. That is how things were done like 20 years ago. By the way, if there is plenty information about that you can find easily with Google, WHY bother other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  For serial RS-232 you will need a `NULL Modem Cable`.  It would not be as fast as a Ethernet or Wireless Network connection.

Comment: I dont have a null modem cable but i have a serial to USB, will it work

Comment: @user3668172 You can connect two serial-to-USB adapters together with a null modem cable (and plug one of the adapters into each computer). You do need the null modem cable, it's basically the serial equivalent of an Ethernet crossover cable.

Comment: You'll still need a null-modem cable (which is a serial cable with pins 2 and 3 crossed) and connect this to the USB/serial-converter. The USB/serial-converter is useful if you have a computer (typically a laptop) without an integrated RS232 port.

Comment: I have a null modem cable and a usb serial cable because in my laptop there is no serial port, will it work? How can i establish a proper communication and can transmit simple text using putty

Comment: Connect the USB serial cable to the laptop.  Then connect the null modem cable to the non-usb end of the USB serial cable and the free end of the null modem cable to the PC.  You will probably find the genders of the cables (i.e. pins or sockets) don't match.  So will need gender changers, which you don't have.  Probably the most cost effective method is then to buy a specific cable for the task.

Comment: just open the apropriate serial ports with putty on both ends using the same parameters and no flow control, you should see characters typed at each end appearing on the other end.

Comment: @albal I have gender changer

Comment: @Jasen you mean to say if i type hi from my pc, it will be reflected on my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

With RS232 protocol we can connect only 1 driver and 1 receiver at a time on one line. For more details check [here](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/2CABB3FD5CAF2F8686256F1D005AD0CD)